# Asp.net: Calling class from codebehind in asp file

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

```
public string GetRandomImage(string StrDirectory, string StrFileName)
{
    Response.Write("Test: GetRandomImage True");
    string GetRandomImage;
    int IntFileCount = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(StrDirectory), "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;
    Random Random1 = new Random();
    IntFileCount = IntFileCount + 1;
    GetRandomImage = StrDirectory + StrFileName + Random1.Next(1, IntFileCount) + ".png";
    Response.Write(GetRandomImage);
    return GetRandomImage;
}
```

this code is in my codebehind file (default.aspx.cs). i want to call it from my default.aspx file. I tried to call with

```
<%# GetRandomImage("images/random/","random_") %>
```

but i have get error. How can I do this? Thank you for all helper(s) and your help(s).

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 2):

You can call it with the fully qualified namespace if its  a static method or with a `this` if its a page method.
Use an equal sign instead of hash

```
<%= this.GetRandomImage("images/random/","random_") %>
```

Comment: I could not understand. What you told me.

Comment: First, i want to thank you for your help. I have used your suggestion. I have not get error but it has not return string value. So i have solved my issue in codebehind's Page_Load event with using asp.net's imageURL attribute of image control. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

# requires a call to DataBind() on the control.

```
protected string GetRandomImage(string StrDirectory, string StrFileName)
{
    Response.Write("Test: GetRandomImage True");
    string GetRandomImage;
    int IntFileCount = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(StrDirectory), "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;
    Random Random1 = new Random();
    IntFileCount = IntFileCount + 1;
    GetRandomImage = StrDirectory + StrFileName + Random1.Next(1, IntFileCount) + ".png";
    Response.Write(GetRandomImage);
    return GetRandomImage;
}
```